# In what order are Android objects that are defined in the manifest initialized?

Tags: manifest, android-contentprovider, android

I try to access my Application from a ContentProvider but it seems that it is being created after the ContentProvider, or at least it's having its `onCreate()` called after my provider. Which begs the question: in what order are these things initialized? Is it defined?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which begs the question: in what order are these things initialized? Is it defined?

`ContentProviders` are initialized before your `Application` instance is. After that will come whatever it is that is triggering your process to exist (e.g., the code to start one of your activities).

Alas, IIRC, this behavior is not well documented.